# How to map a column from another table?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, database-design, entity-framework-core

I have two tables `articles` and `content` (1-to-1 relation). `content` table contains an article body in JSON format (PostgreSQL). The tables were split for performance reasons, as the content is too large.

**Articles** table:

```
| Column          | Type   |
|-----------------|--------|
| id              | int    |
| title           | string |
| *other columns* | xxx    |
```

**Content** table:

```
| Column    | Type  |
|-----------|-------|
| articleId | int   |
| content   | jsonb |
```

I'm trying to map this tables into single entity `Article`:

```cs
namespace Domain.Models
{
    [Table("articles")]
    public class Article
    {
        [Column("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("title")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Column("content")]
        public string Content { get; set; }

        <...> // other columns
    }
}
```

My `DbContext`:

```cs
namespace Domain
{
    public class MasterDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Question:** *How to map `Content` property from `content` table?*

---

My dumb solution: I just created a non-materialized view and map `Article` entity to this "table":

```sql
CREATE VIEW articles_with_content AS
    SELECT a.*, c.content
    FROM articles AS a
    JOIN content AS c ON c."articleId" = a.id;
```

Can someone suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a Content class

Then in your Article class have it as:

```
public Content Content { get; set; }
```

Then configure your models (in your MasterDbContext class)

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
         {
            builder.Entity<Article>(b =>
            {
                b.HasOne(c => c.Content)

               .WithOne(a => a.Article)

               .HasForeignKey<Content>(d => d.ArticleID);
            });

         }
```

Comment: But in that case the `Content` property will be an object, not a string

Comment: Right, and you'll access the article content like this: article.Content.Content